# How to invoke a method of a class from another project by Rest Api in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-tomee, java-ee-8

I need to call a method from another project in eclipse, I tried to add the project to classpath of the current project (Right click on project -> properties -> java build path -> projects) but I got an error and exception (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) and ( java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) and I couldn't fix that. I know there is another way to do this job by using Rest Api. please help me!! Thanks.

I want to call (getSample2) to my current project:

```
public List<String> getSample2 (String fileName, int minFrequency, int maxFrequency) {
    List<SampleMultyFreq> fd = getSamples(fileName, minFrequency, maxFrequency);
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    for(SampleMultyFreq ss: fd) {
        ls.add(ss.getFrequencies().toString());
    }
    return ls;
}
```

I created this method in the same project with (getsample2) for calling (getSample2) method easy. I don't know it is a right way or not.

```
@GET
@Path("GET_SAMPLE_API")
public Response getSampleApi (String fileName) {
    List<String> ss = new DataReader2NewPods().getSample2(fileName, 1, 9);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(ss).build();
}
```

and Finally I wrote this method in my current project for sending request to get (getSampleApi) like this but I don't know the methods that I used is correct or not I copied another method that was for download a file from AWS cloud by using rest api:

```
public String getSampleMethdByRest (String fileName) {
    
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(fileName)) {
        
        System.out.println(" print to test 1:");
        
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/project-dev/ss/GET_SAMPLE_API/";
        
        final Response resp = client.target(url).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).get(Response.class);
        
        if (resp.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            System.out.println(" print to test 2:");
            
            InputStream inputStream = (InputStream)resp.getEntity();
            }
        }
    System.out.println(" print to test 3:");
    
    return Constants.root + File.separator +
    Config.getInstance().getProperties().getProperty("temp_folder") + File.separator + fileName;            
}
```

and this is the output:

print to test 1:

print to test 3:

C:\home\project\temp_folder\data_98F4ABFB7806_16480262_1595325764285_len_2528.txt

Would you please help me. many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could package a .jar of the project and use it as a library.

Comment: @IvanDimitrov I did use this way but I got those Exceptions (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) and ( java.lang.ClassNotFoundException). it did not work. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: The way I would do it is to fix my errors. If there isn't any reason for the projects to be separated like that I would not do it.

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace? Most probably the jar files are not available at your runtime. How are you building and packaging the app>